# When to create a new Flux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I was wondering what the best practice or convention is when creating stores in Flux when working with an API

Let's say we have a list of 'projects', the API call would eventually fill a Store called **ProjectStore** in **_projects**

Then, when a user selects a project, you want to load the Project specific data. Would you add this to the same **ProjectStore** as **_activeProject**, or create a seperate Store for it?

Same for when you load the Todo's within that Project. It would make sense to put these in a **TodoStore**, but what about a specific Todo within the Todos within the Project?

I hope the above makes sense :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the `ProjectStore`to store both `_projects`and `_activeProject`.

I have done as a rule in my React projects to create a new store for each model.
For instance: Let's say that I have an application that serves messages and accounts. I would then have a `MessageStore`and an `AccountStore`. Then use these accordingly to their domain.
E.g., when I want to get some messages from the backend (through an API), I store them in the `MessageStore`. The same goes for the `AccountStore`.

As your project becomes larger and larger, you would probably have to reconsider refactoring something into a new store. For instance, if you want to add advertisement to your site, you could create an `AdsStore`.

My rule of thumb is to try to separate stores by their domain, but don't make the structure more complex than it has to be.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for your insight .. I was actually on my way to have one Store for each Model in the Express API, but it felts wrong somehow. Wasn't sure if it was the "Flux Way". I could see a benefit for having a Store called "ActiveProject" for when a specific Project is loaded and you are browsing the different ProjectSettings, ProjectTeam, ProjectOverview pages.

Comment: I agree. If the "new" data retrieved in an "ActiveProject" demands a lot of new logic and other API calls, it would be beneficial to create a new store.